# How do get my own question unprotected?

Tags: support, protected-questions

I have a question on Stack Overflow which has been protected. I do not have the reputation required to unprotect it.

The question has had a number of off-topic responses from people who apparently haven’t read the question, but one of the chief offenders is the one who actually protected the question. That seems inappropriate and not a little ironic.

There certainly hasn’t been the sort of responses which appear to be the reason for protection: no me-toos or thanks.

How do I get my question unprotected?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just ask. You can post a request on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, or flag your question for moderator attention; either one will do.

For now, you needn't bother; I've taken the liberty of unprotecting your question, as there was clearly no need for it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I’ll follow this up next time the issue arises.

Comment: @Manngo additionally, for Stack Overflow, you could jump into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where normally enough regulars hang around with the privileges to both protect and unprotect questions. We have a [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq).